# How to make a screenshot of an entire e-mail body without scrolling?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using OL2010 and want to make a screenshot of the entire e-mail (not only of the "Screen").

Can it be done with VBA or an external program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176340) on how to achieve this using C#. Pay attention to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4176361/22114), it explains why there are cases where it may not be possible at all.

For some VB example code on how to capture screenshots, see [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161299) from Microsoft. Here are the most relevant parts:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Private Type PALETTEENTRY
    peRed As Byte
    peGreen As Byte
    peBlue As Byte
    peFlags As Byte
End Type

Private Type LOGPALETTE
    palVersion As Integer
    palNumEntries As Integer
    palPalEntry(255) As PALETTEENTRY  ' Enough for 256 colors.
End Type

Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(7) As Byte
End Type

Private Const RASTERCAPS As Long = 38
Private Const RC_PALETTE As Long = &H100
Private Const SIZEPALETTE As Long = 104

Private Type RECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function CreateCompatibleDC Lib "GDI32" (ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateCompatibleBitmap Lib "GDI32" ( _
    ByVal hDC As Long, _
    ByVal nWidth As Long, _
    ByVal nHeight As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "GDI32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal iCapabilitiy As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetSystemPaletteEntries Lib "GDI32" ( _
    ByVal hDC As Long, _
    ByVal wStartIndex As Long, _
    ByVal wNumEntries As Long, _
    lpPaletteEntries As PALETTEENTRY) As Long
Private Declare Function CreatePalette Lib "GDI32" (lpLogPalette As LOGPALETTE) As Long
Private Declare Function SelectObject Lib "GDI32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function BitBlt Lib "GDI32" ( _
    ByVal hDCDest As Long, _
    ByVal XDest As Long, _
    ByVal YDest As Long, _
    ByVal nWidth As Long, _
    ByVal nHeight As Long, _
    ByVal hDCSrc As Long, _
    ByVal XSrc As Long, _
    ByVal YSrc As Long, _
    ByVal dwRop As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DeleteDC Lib "GDI32" (ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "USER32" () As Long
Private Declare Function SelectPalette Lib "GDI32" ( _
    ByVal hDC As Long, _
    ByVal hPalette As Long, _
    ByVal bForceBackground As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function RealizePalette Lib "GDI32" (ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowDC Lib "USER32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "USER32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "USER32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, lpRect As RECT) As Long
Private Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "USER32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "USER32" () As Long

Private Type PicBmp
    Size As Long
    Type As Long
    hBmp As Long
    hPal As Long
    Reserved As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "olepro32.dll" ( _
    PicDesc As PicBmp, _
    RefIID As GUID, _
    ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, _
    IPic As IPicture) As Long

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'
' CreateBitmapPicture
'    - Creates a bitmap type Picture object from a bitmap and
'      palette.
'
' hBmp
'    - Handle to a bitmap.
'
' hPal
'    - Handle to a Palette.
'    - Can be null if the bitmap doesn't use a palette.
'
' Returns
'    - Returns a Picture object containing the bitmap.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Function CreateBitmapPicture(ByVal hBmp As Long, ByVal hPal As Long) As Picture
    Dim r As Long
    Dim Pic As PicBmp
    ' IPicture requires a reference to "Standard OLE Types."
    Dim IPic As IPicture
    Dim IID_IDispatch As GUID

    ' Fill in with IDispatch Interface ID.
    With IID_IDispatch
        .Data1 = &H20400
        .Data4(0) = &HC0
        .Data4(7) = &H46
    End With

    ' Fill Pic with necessary parts.
    With Pic
        .Size = Len(Pic)    ' Length of structure.
        .Type = vbPicTypeBitmap   ' Type of Picture (bitmap).
        .hBmp = hBmp  ' Handle to bitmap.
        .hPal = hPal  ' Handle to palette (may be null).
    End With

    ' Create Picture object.
    r = OleCreatePictureIndirect(Pic, IID_IDispatch, 1, IPic)

    ' Return the new Picture object.
    Set CreateBitmapPicture = IPic
End Function

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'
' CaptureWindow
'    - Captures any portion of a window.
'
' hWndSrc
'    - Handle to the window to be captured.
'
' LeftSrc, TopSrc, WidthSrc, HeightSrc
'    - Specify the portion of the window to capture.
'    - Dimensions need to be specified in pixels.
'
' Returns
'    - Returns a Picture object containing a bitmap of the specified
'      portion of the window that was captured.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Function CaptureWindow( _
    ByVal hWndSrc As Long, _
    ByVal LeftSrc As Long, _
    ByVal TopSrc As Long, _
    ByVal WidthSrc As Long, _
    ByVal HeightSrc As Long) As Picture

    Dim hDCMemory As Long
    Dim hBmp As Long
    Dim hBmpPrev As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim hDCSrc As Long
    Dim hPal As Long
    Dim hPalPrev As Long
    Dim RasterCapsScrn As Long
    Dim HasPaletteScrn As Long
    Dim PaletteSizeScrn As Long
    Dim LogPal As LOGPALETTE

    ' Get device context for entire window.
    hDCSrc = GetWindowDC(hWndSrc)

    ' Create a memory device context for the copy process.
    hDCMemory = CreateCompatibleDC(hDCSrc)
    ' Create a bitmap and place it in the memory DC.
    hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDCSrc, WidthSrc, HeightSrc)
    hBmpPrev = SelectObject(hDCMemory, hBmp)

    ' Get screen properties.
    RasterCapsScrn = GetDeviceCaps(hDCSrc, RASTERCAPS) ' Raster
    ' capabilities.
    HasPaletteScrn = RasterCapsScrn And RC_PALETTE ' Palette
    ' support.
    PaletteSizeScrn = GetDeviceCaps(hDCSrc, SIZEPALETTE) ' Size of
    ' palette.

    ' If the screen has a palette make a copy and realize it.
    If HasPaletteScrn And (PaletteSizeScrn = 256) Then
        ' Create a copy of the system palette.
        LogPal.palVersion = &H300
        LogPal.palNumEntries = 256
        r = GetSystemPaletteEntries(hDCSrc, 0, 256, _
        LogPal.palPalEntry(0))
        hPal = CreatePalette(LogPal)
        ' Select the new palette into the memory DC and realize it.
        hPalPrev = SelectPalette(hDCMemory, hPal, 0)
        r = RealizePalette(hDCMemory)
    End If

    ' Copy the on-screen image into the memory DC.
    r = BitBlt(hDCMemory, 0, 0, WidthSrc, HeightSrc, hDCSrc, LeftSrc, TopSrc, vbSrcCopy)

    ' Remove the new copy of the  on-screen image.
    hBmp = SelectObject(hDCMemory, hBmpPrev)

    ' If the screen has a palette get back the palette that was
    ' selected in previously.
    If HasPaletteScrn And (PaletteSizeScrn = 256) Then
        hPal = SelectPalette(hDCMemory, hPalPrev, 0)
    End If

    ' Release the device context resources back to the system.
    r = DeleteDC(hDCMemory)
    r = ReleaseDC(hWndSrc, hDCSrc)

    ' Call CreateBitmapPicture to create a picture object from the
    ' bitmap and palette handles. Then return the resulting picture
    ' object.
    Set CaptureWindow = CreateBitmapPicture(hBmp, hPal)
End Function
```

Comment: Hi treb, thanks man. Edit: Wow this actually seems really good. I'll try that!

Comment: Do you know if I can find out whether the "unscrolled area" (below the actual) was rendered? Or do you know if that counts for OL as well?

Comment: Sorry, I see no way of finding out programmatically, it depends complete on how the application handles the drawing of the window. As for Outlook, I think you will have to try it in order to find out...

Comment: Ok Thanks! I'll find out next week.